Limit character number in Text Field - Swift
I am struggling to limit the number of characters in a text field to a 2 digit number.
TextField("", text: $tableNumber)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)

Everything I tried must be outdated for iOS 17/Xcode 15 as previous solutions don't work
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.
======================

I think this simple use case can be achieved with this approach:
@State private var stableNumber: String = ""

var body: some View {
    TextField("", text: $stableNumber)
        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        .onChange(of: stableNumber) {
            self.stableNumber = String(self.stableNumber.prefix(2)) //<- here
        }
}

Output

